# Diff HTTP PUT method in Spring/JPA/Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I'm wondering what's the best practice when using a PUT method to update a specific property of an entity stored in DB.

Let's see for example the following json that is received on the Rest Controller:

```
{"id":1, "surname":"Doe"}
```

The entity that we have stored looks something like this:

```
public class Employee {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String surname;
    Date createdAt;
    Date updatedAt;
}
```

I omitted the annotations for simplicity purposes.

What I'd like to achieve is that on the RestController I receive something like this:

```
@PutRequest
public Employee updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    repo.saveAndFlush(employee);
}
```

So, if I do it, then the existing fields for the `name` and timestamps will be set to null because the provided entity doesn't contain such fields.

I'm wondering if there's a way to run the following actions:

- Load the entity with the ID provided on DB
- Update the fields provided in the Json/Request Body.
- Persist the updated entity -> This can be done the same way I've showed in the code.

I'm aware that it exists the @JsonIdentity and @JsonIdentifyreference(alwaysAsId=true) which I use in conjunction with resolvers to fetch the data from DB for fetching a nested entity where only the ID is provided rather the entity itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PATCH` method is designed for that functionality.

`PUT` should be used when you are replacing the whole resource - that means setting `null` on fields that you didn't provide in request.

`PATCH` is used for updating a resource, you can update a single field, or all the fields, your choice.

Be aware that the actual database update may not automagically work, just because you changed the HTTP method. For Hibernate there is a `@DynamicUpdate` that provides the same functionality. Without `@DynamicUpdate` the fields set to `null` will be updated, but with `@DynamicUpdate`only the fields that were modified will be updated.

Comment: To be more precise, patch is a set of instructions a server should apply on certain resources to transform the state of the resource to a desired one. As also mentioned by [William Durand](https://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) using [JSON Merge Patch format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7396) is probably the closes thing to what plenty of people consider a partial update done either via PUT or PATCH.